# Didn't get 1000 Mbps speed on self crimpled LAN cable

Tags: networking, router, lan

I have New D-Link cat 6 stranded 20 meter LAN cable on which I want to run my internet connection. Problem is that I'm unable run it on 1 Gbps speed only running at 100 Mbps. While the LAN cable **(solid)** 1 meter provided by the router manufacturer is doing good.

The RJ 45 connection made by me is very good no loose wires , all 8 wires are fully deep in RJ 45 CONNECTOR, each wire is giving DC electric signal to other end of the wire, still I'm unable to find the problem.

**Edit 1** :- I'm using random colour combinations but both the ends have similar colour code , so the pattern is straight through ( no crossover cabling is used)

**Edit 2** :- After following T- 568B colour code my ethernet speed problem is solved. Earlier I'm being extra smart for not giving any importance to T-568B standard .

Comment: What pattern did you use? Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The twisted pairs matter for noise cancellation purposes.

- Pin 1 must be on the same twisted pair as pin 2.
- Pin 3 must be on the same twisted pair as pin **6** (Yes, 6).
- Pin 4 & 5.
- Pin 7 & 8.

Just follow EIA/TIA-568B on both ends like everyone else does.

Comment: Thanks Spiff following TIA-568B solved my problem .

Comment: @BusyBusiness Great. Click the checkmark next to my Answer to accept it as the answer that solved it for you. This will mark your question as resolved.